# Comprobar si un arreglo de datos esta vacio

Tags: php

La ejecucion que hago me lanza un arreglo ya sea vacio o lleno de datos, necesito comprobar si el arreglo tiene o no datos:

```
public function valUser($item){
    $query = "select * from usuarios where usuario = ? and password = ?";
    $res = $this->bd->Execute($query, [$item[0],$item[1]]);
    if (strcmp($res->status,"ok_query_success")==0){
        $valor = $this->estado["success"]=$res->data;
        print_r($valor);
        if (condition) {
            $this->estado["status"]="ok_log_in";
        }else if(condition){
            $this->estado["status"]="err_log_in";
        }

        //$this->estado["success"]=$res->data;
        //$this->getEstado();                 
    }
}
```

El print_r me lanza esto cuando esta vacio:

[image: vacio]

y asi cuando tiene datos:

[image: lleno]

Necesito meter una condicion si esta lleno mande un mensaje y si esta vacio otro como se muestras en la función.

Comment: Intenta `if(!empty($valor)) {`

Comment: Si funciona, pero utilize este if (!is_null($valor)) que igualmente funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esta función, isset comprueba que una variable esté definida y no es null, luego simplemente queda contar los elementos del array.

```
function array_has_data($array){
    return isset($array) && count($array) > 0;
}
```